# Biber suddenly stopped compiling

Tags: compiling, biber

I have a long literature.bib file. It has been running without a problem, suddenly it seems to not run further:

```
INFO - Logfile is 'main.blg'
INFO - Reading 'main.bcf'
INFO - Found 27 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Globbing data source 'literature/literature.bib'
INFO - Globbed data source 'literature/literature.bib' to literature/literature.bib
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'literature/literature.bib' for section 0
INFO - LaTeX decoding ...
INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'literature/literature.bib'
```

It stays there and never generates the literature in the text nor shows an error.

Comment: run `biber --cache`  in a terminal. This reports back the path of the cache, delete it and try again.

Comment: It worked!! thanks!!!